# Resetting controls to their initial values in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I'm learning OSX development in Swift and I have a slider (NSSliderCell) which has a minValue 0, maxValue 100 and a current value set to 50 in Interfce Builder.

I want to make a function that can reset the slider value back to 50 when I press a button. However, I can't find a function that gives me this property from the NSSliderCell. I'm assuming there is one because it would seem redundant to have to keep track of these values both in a XIB and in a controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value set in IB is just for when it is loaded from nib. 
If you want a default value to "reset" to, do it in viewWillAppear in a view controller and use NSUserDefaults to register and read your defaults. 
Create a constant global to your view controller or in a constants header file. 
Resetting is just setting to some value.

Comment: Just to add to this. The "function" to programmatically set the value of the slider is inherited from the superclass. You want to use `intergerValue` property (or whatever variant is a appropriate for your data type). So create a button and in its action method set the slider to a default value that you store in your model.